# Unit Test Load Testing Visual Studio Cloud not able to initialize SQL Server connection

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2, stress-testing

I am trying to test WCF endpoint stress testing using VS 2013 Cloud Load testing. I have created unit testes which are running fine. To make my unit test work I had to pass some random set of values to the endpoint. So I created a database `haavinf` with valid values and randomly selecting them as a input for my WCF endpoint.

I am trying to use VS 2013 Cloud load testing and my tests are failing at Unit test Initialization test.

> Initialization method WCFLoadTests.Tests.Init threw exception.
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException:
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).

Do I need to do some setting on cloud? or what?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all who read my question and spent their time to help me resolve it.

I have fixed this issue by simply using Code First technique in my Unit Tests. Earlier I was using Database first ( was being Lazy) and generated connection string ( providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  ) was giving error.

Many thanks,